# Use jQuery to compare server time and current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

I'm trying to convert VBScript to Javascript, using jQuery to compare the server time and current time.

```
If Not IsDate(frmLogDetail.hidServerTime.value) Then
frmLogDetail.hidServerTime.value = Now
End If
frmLogDetail.hidTimeOffset.value = DateDiff("s", Time, TimeValue(frmLogDetail.hidServerTime.value) )
```

This is what I have:

```
var hdServerTime = $("#hidServerTime");

if (!IsDate(hdServerTime)) {
   hdServerTime.val(new Date());
   alert(hdServerTime.val());
}

var dateSelected = $("#hidServerTime").val();
var hdTimeOffset = $("#hidTimeOffset").val();
hdTimeOffset = DateDiff(Date.now, new Date(dateSelected));

function DateDiff(first, second) {
            return (second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
        }
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't magically do everything. You're going to need to actually do some thinking.

Comment: Check out http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: You probably want to *call* `Date.now()`, instead of passing it as a function

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client side scripting language, as such you will not have access to the server time unless you support it with server side scripting such as PHP.  `Date.now()` will give you the client side time in milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

I find your code confusing (I assume you are doing a PHP implementation? Hidden div/span?) so i'm just going to answer with what I would do.

One way of getting the server side time is to serve the page using PHP, and defining the variable in Javascript globally before you actually run the Javascript client side. You would do something like this (for example) in the `<head>` tag of your page :

```
<?php 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
         var servertime = ".time()."; 
         </script>" 
?>
```

Then in Javascript you will have the variable `servertime` to compare with something like this:

```
//Get time difference in milliseconds
var timeDifference = Date.now() - servertime;
```

This implementation is nice because you don't need jQuery at all, and you aren't dealing with some of the SEO issues with hiding elements on the page etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
var hdTimeOffset = $("#hidTimeOffset").val();
hdTimeOffset = …;
```

That's not how you assign a value with jQuery. This code just assigns to the variable `hdTimeOffset`, which is not some magic reference to the DOM. Instead, use

```
var hdTimeOffset = …;
$("#hidTimeOffset").val(hdTimeOffset);
```

(see [docs for jQuery `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/))